# How to edit a redirecting library of SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, redirect, sharepoint-library

I have a library in SharePoint which redirects to another page.

I have added the following script for redirection using script editor web part.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://MYSERVERNAME.com/Sites/Sitename/SitePages/Home.aspx">
```

When i try to open the library in browser for editing, it redirects me to that target page. Is there any way I can stop redirection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the page in maintenance mode. Temporarily close the web part. Then edit page. After completion enable the web part.

https://sharepointthing.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/how-to-access-page-in-maintenance-mode/

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to do this is if you edit the page in SharePoint Designer.

Next time..

1. Put the script in a file that you upload into a site assets library.
2. Add the CEWP to the page and link to the file that you added with any redirect info. I would use JavaScript.

This way if you need to recover the page or do any work you can change the file name breaking the link to the file stored in the CEWP.

****You can also add ?Contents=1 to the end of the url. This will take you into the web part maintenance page so you can close out the bad web part.****

Comment: As it is library we can't edit it in SharePoint designer. Or is there any way?
But adding ?Contents=1 works.
Thanks..!!

Comment: @AnkitJetani remember that you can add a Content Editor Web Part to the page and link to a text file that has the HTML or JavaScript in it. This will save you next time. All you would need to do is rename the filename.